# Loop for ordered pairs equivalent in Common Lisp

Tags: loops, iteration, lisp, common-lisp

Suppose you have a list and want to generate a list of all ordered pairs of elements, e.g. the list is `'(1 3 5 7 9)` and the desired result is

```
((1 . 1) (1 . 3) (1 . 5) (1 . 7) (1 . 9) (3 . 3) (3 . 5) (3 . 7) (3 . 9)
 (5 . 5) (5 . 7) (5 . 9) (7 . 7) (7 . 9) (9 . 9))
```

If it were arrays in C with indices one could have one `for` nested inside another, and let the second index start at the respective outer index, i.e.

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int arr[] = {1,3,5,7,9};

    for (int i=0; i<5; ++i) {
        for (int j = i; j<5; ++j) {
            printf("(%d, %d) ", arr[i], arr[j]);
        }
    }
    puts("");

    return 0;
}
```

Now, obviously the above does only print the desired result.

The index version should translate rather straightforwardly to Common Lisp.

My question now is: **how would an idiomatic Common Lisp version look like for the [*for-as-in-list*](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_abab.htm) type of iteration?**

I have something that works but it looks kinda forced:

```
(loop
     for cdrs on list
     for x in list nconc
       (loop
          for y in cdrs collect (cons x y)))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a slightly simpler version:

```
CL-USER> (loop for x on '(1 3 5 7 9)
               nconc (loop for y in x collect (cons (car x) y)))

((1 . 1) (1 . 3) (1 . 5) (1 . 7) (1 . 9) (3 . 3) (3 . 5) (3 . 7) (3 . 9) (5 . 5) (5 . 7) (5 . 9) (7 . 7) (7 . 9) (9 . 9))
```

Comment: Ah, didn't think of that one. One minor thing that is unsatisfactory is that now the "types" of `x` and `y` are different (at least I feel that way).

Comment: @Aroob we can tweak it as `(loop for xs on '(1 3 5 7 9)  nconc (loop for y in xs with x = (car xs) collect (cons x y)))`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see the “forced”.  In C, you have two nested loops.  In Common Lisp, you have two nested loops.  That's because the problem has this structure.

You might be confused by the wordiness of `loop`, but that's just the way it is designed.  At least you don't have to wrangle indices by yourself.

If you don't like it, there are other constructs, e. g.:

```
(mapcon (lambda (sublist)
          (mapcar (lambda (second)
                    (cons (first sublist) second))
                  sublist)
        list)

(do* ((cdrs list (cdr cdrs))
      (car (first list) (first cdrs))
      (pairs ()))
     ((null car) (nreverse pairs))
  (dolist (cdr cdrs)
    (push (cons car cdr) pairs)))
```

You can also use vectors (i. e. one-dimensional arrays), and recreate that indexy-printy C feeling:

```
(let ((v #(1 3 5 7 9)))
  (loop :for i :below (length v)
        :do (loop :for j :upfrom i :below (length v)
                  :do (format t "(~a, ~a) " (aref v i) (aref v j))))
  (terpri))
```

EDIT after comment:  to show the relation, you can make `x` dependent on the sublist:

```
(loop :for cdrs :on list
      :for car := (car cdrs)
      :nconc (loop :for cdr :in cdrs
                   :collect (cons car cdr)))
```

You could also use a vector and have an index only for the start of the subvector:

```
(let ((vector #(1 3 5 7 9)))
  (loop :for x :across vector
        :and i :upfrom 0
        :nconc (loop :for y :across (subseq vector i)
                     :collect (cons x y))))
```

Comment: To clarify: by "forced" I mean that (at least in my version) I have to introduce a new structure to get my result. There is a difference between "begin the second iteration at the current element of the first iteration" and "begin the second iteration in this (unrelated) helper structure" (hopefully 
that cleared things up a bit).

Also I didn't mean to advocate the explicitly indexy way, mind you, as I quite like the wordiness of
`loop` :).

Comment: @Aroob The loop is not creating any helper structures. It just loops over the cons-cells of the proper list. The difference between the C and Lisp solutions is simply due to the difference between an array and a linked list. If you used the same data structure in both languages, the solutions would be the same.

Answer (score 1):

**By using `map` family functions only**

This is quite lispy in my view (and maybe a solution for `loop`-haters):

```
(defun 1st-conses (l)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (cons (car l) x)) l))

(mapcan #'1st-conses (maplist #'identity '(1 3 5 7 9))
;; ((1 . 1) (1 . 3) (1 . 5) (1 . 7) (1 . 9) (3 . 3) (3 . 5) (3 . 7) (3 . 9)
;;  (5 . 5) (5 . 7) (5 . 9) (7 . 7) (7 . 9) (9 . 9))
```

**By recursion only**

And tail-call-recursive solution for `loop`-haters:

```
(defun 1st-conses (l)
  (labels ((.1st-conses (l fst acc)
             (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
                   (t (.1st-conses (cdr l) fst (cons (cons fst (car l))
                                                                acc))))))
    (.1st-conses l (car l) '())))

(defun combine-down (l &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null l) acc)
        (t (pairing-down (cdr l) (nconc acc (1st-conses l))))))

(combine-down '(1 3 5 7 9))
;; ((1 . 1) (1 . 3) (1 . 5) (1 . 7) (1 . 9) (3 . 3) (3 . 5) (3 . 7) (3 . 9)
;;  (5 . 5) (5 . 7) (5 . 9) (7 . 7) (7 . 9) (9 . 9))
```

**By small `loop` functions**

The fused version of these three functions are presented in the other answers:

```
(defun tails (l)
  (loop for x on l collect x))

(defun 1st-conses (l)
  (loop for x in l collect (cons (car l) x)))

(loop for l in (tails '(1 3 5 7 9))
      nconc (1st-conses l))
```

**More general solution with small functions**

Combine any of these three functions - each presented with a `map`-version, a `loop`-version and a tail-call-recursion version. - So you can create by choice a

- purely `map` solution
- purely `loop` solution or a
- purely recursive solution.

or you

- mix them up deliberately ;)

The functions are:

```
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; function collecting all `cdr`s of a list:
;; (tails '(a b c))
;; ;; returns: ((A B C) (B C) (C))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; with `map`s
(defun tails (l)
  (maplist #'identity l))

;; with `loop`
(defun tails (l)
  (loop for x on l collect x))

;; tail-call-recursion
(defun tails (l &optional (acc '()))
  (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
        (t (tails (cdr l) (cons l acc)))))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; function collecting `car` of a list `cons`ed with each list element
;; (1st-conses '(a b c))
;; ;; returns: ((A . A) (A . B) (A . C))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; with `map`s
(defun 1st-conses (l)
  (mapcar #'(lambda (x) (cons (car l) x)) l))

;; with `loop`
(defun 1st-conses (l)
  (loop for x in l collect (cons (car l) x)))

;; tail-call-recursion
(defun 1st-conses (l)
  (labels ((.1st-conses (l fst acc)
             (cond ((null l) (nreverse acc))
                   (t (.1st-conses (cdr l) fst (cons (cons fst (car l))
                                                                acc))))))
    (.1st-conses l (car l) '())))

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;; applying the second function on the first functions' results
;; (combine-down '(a b c))
;; ;; returning: ((A . A) (A . B) (A . C) (B . B) (B . C) (C . C))
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; with `map`s
(defun combine-down (l)
  (mapcan #'1st-conses (tails l)))

;; with `loop`
(defun combine-down (l)
  (loop for x in (tails l)
        nconc (1st-conses x)))

;; with tail-call-recursion
(defun combine-down (l)
  (labels ((.combine-down (l acc)
            (cond ((null l) acc)
                  (t (.combine-down (cdr l) 
                                    (nconc acc 
                                           (1st-conses (car l))))))))
    (.combine-down (tails l) '())))
```

And then:

```
(combine-down '(1 3 5 7 9))
;; ((1 . 1) (1 . 3) (1 . 5) (1 . 7) (1 . 9) (3 . 3) (3 . 5) (3 . 7) (3 . 9)
;;  (5 . 5) (5 . 7) (5 . 9) (7 . 7) (7 . 9) (9 . 9))
```

**Imperative way**

Just for fun, I translated the imperative cpp code as literally as possible -
because as a truly multi-paradigm language ... :

```
(let ((arr '(1 3 5 7 9))
      (res '()))
  (loop for i from 0 below 5 by 1
        do (loop for j from i below 5 by 1
                 do (setq res (cons (cons (elt arr i)
                                          (elt arr j))
                                          res))))
  (nreverse res))
```

It returns correctly:

```
((1 . 1) (1 . 3) (1 . 5) (1 . 7) (1 . 9) (3 . 3) (3 . 5) (3 . 7) (3 . 9)
 (5 . 5) (5 . 7) (5 . 9) (7 . 7) (7 . 9) (9 . 9))
```